# How to run a threaded function that returns a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-multithreading

Working with Python 3.6, what I’m looking to accomplish is to create a function that continuously scrapes dynamic/changing data from a webpage, while the rest of the script executes, and is able to reference the data returned from the continuous function.

I know this is likely a threading task, however I’m not super knowledgeable in it yet. Pseudo-code I might think looks something like this

```
def continuous_scraper():
    # Pull data from webpage
    scraped_table = pd.read_html(url)
    return scraped_table

# start the continuous scraper function here, to run either indefinitely, or preferably stop after a predefined amount of time
scraped_table = thread(continuous_scraper)

# the rest of the script is run here, making use of the updating “scraped_table”
while True:
    print(scraped_table[“Col_1”].iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple example using some stock market page that seems to update every couple of seconds.

```py
import threading, time

import pandas as pd

# A lock is used to ensure only one thread reads or writes the variable at any one time
scraped_table_lock = threading.Lock()

# Initially set to None so we know when its value has changed
scraped_table = None

# This bad-boy will be called only once in a separate thread
def continuous_scraper():
    # Tell Python this is a global variable, so it rebinds scraped_table 
    # instead of creating a local variable that is also named scraped_table
    global scraped_table
    url = r"https://tradingeconomics.com/australia/stock-market"
    while True:
        # Pull data from webpage
        result = pd.read_html(url, match="Dow Jones")[0]
        
        # Acquire the lock to ensure thread-safety, then assign the new result
        # This is done after read_html returns so it doesn't hold the lock for so long
        with scraped_table_lock:
            scraped_table = result
        
        # You don't wanna flog the server, so wait 2 seconds after each 
        # response before sending another request
        time.sleep(2)

# Make the thread daemonic, so the thread doesn't continue to run once the 
# main script and any other non-daemonic threads have ended
scraper_thread = threading.Thread(target=continuous_scraper, daemon=True)

# start the continuous scraper function here, to run either indefinitely, or 
# preferably stop after a predefined amount of time
scraper_thread.start()

# the rest of the script is run here, making use of the updating “scraped_table”
for _ in range(100):
    print("Time:", time.time())
    
    # Acquire the lock to ensure thread-safety
    with scraped_table_lock:
        # Check if it has been changed from the default value of None
        if scraped_table is not None:
            print("     ", scraped_table)
        else:
            print("scraped_table is None")
    
    # You probably don't wanna flog your stdout, either, dawg!
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Be sure to read about multithreaded programming and thread safety. It's easy to make mistakes. If there is a bug, it often only manifests in rare and seemingly random occasions, making it difficult to debug.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, awesome example. Thanks for steering me in the right direction, I can work with this. I will award the bounty when SO let's me in a couple hours. Thanks again, I learned something today :D

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) library and `Pool` class.

The docs have multiple examples of how to use it.

Question itself is too general to make a simple answer.